# unable to locate element : selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm a newbie in coding with python and selenium. I try to find an element in a web-page by its class name.

```
    <input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" 
           autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" 
           aria-label="Adresse e-mail ou numéro de téléphone" name="identifier" 
           value="" autocapitalize="none" id="identifierId" dir="ltr" 
           data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">
```

But each time I've tried I have this error.

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".whsOnd zHQkBf"}

I don't understand why because I verified and I think that it's not in an iframe so I don't understand why do I have this message and I don't know how to manage the error.

Here are the pictures of my code and the html :

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hzg9.png)

[The HTML of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdHYC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your code and the html. Are you sure it is not in a iframe?

If not you can perhaps try to use xpath to find the element.
When inspecting the webpage in chrome you can right click the element and say copy -> copy xpath. I do recommend looking into xpath, so you know what you are searching for.

Edit:
Try using only one class name, since find_element_by_class_name() only accepts one.

This:
driver.find_element_by_class_name("zHQkBf")

instead of this:
driver.find_element_by_class_name("whsOnd zHQkBf")

Comment: Fisrtly thanks for your help ! I can re-edit the post and join pictures of my code and the htlm. I'm not clever with the xpath but i will watch some tutos on youtube about this. Check again the post with pictures and tell me if you see some errors or don't know... Thanks a lot

Comment: Seleniums find_element_by_class_name can only take one classe name as far as i know.

Therefore try the following and see if it works:
driver.find_element_by_class_name("zHQkBf")